# How to make ExposedDropdownMenu's width match its widest MenuItem

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a composable ExposedDropdownMenu similar to this.

```kotlin
ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
    expanded = expanded,
    onExpandedChange = {
        expanded = !expanded
    }
) {

    OutlinedTextField(
        readOnly = true,
        value = selected,
        onValueChange = { },
        trailingIcon = {
            ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(
                expanded = expanded
            )
        }
    )

    ExposedDropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded,
        onDismissRequest = {
            expanded = false
        }
    ) {
        options.forEach { selection ->
            DropdownMenuItem(
                onClick = {
                    selected = selection
                    expanded = false
                }
            ) {
                Text(text = selection)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting view looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to reduce the width of the the dropdown so it actually wraps around its widest menu option.

And I've already tried setting modifiers at all levels of the composition to ensure no child is widening the parent, but to no success.